# system of equations mod 7

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic, matrix-equations

I am to solve the system of equations below for the field mod 7.  I am also to solve another system of equations that's the same system as below but with the right hand sides replaced with 2, 4, and 1 respectively.  I was told that these two problems could be solved simultaneously using an agumented matrix but wouldn't this completely change the general solutions for $x,y,z$?

Thanks in advance!

> $$x + 4y +5z=1$$
>   $$6y +4z=2$$
>   $$4x +3z =3$$

Comment: Are you familiar with Gauss elimination?

Comment: Remember that the integers mod $7$ is a field, and Gaussian elimination is valid for any field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to solve multiple systems, the thing to do is express them as  matrix equations $AX=B_1$ (and $AX=B_2$, etc.), where $X=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, compute $A^{-1}$, and then the solution will be $X=A^{-1}B_1$ (and $X=A^{-1}B_2$, etc.).

Here $$A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&4&5\\0&6&4\\4&0&3\end{matrix}\right)$$